# Change what the power button do changing automatically

Tags: windows-10, power, power-management, control-panel

I changed the power button settings on my computer to do nothing when I press the power button. 
It stays in this state for a while, but after a bit, it changes itself back to pressing the power button turns off the computer.

The only power-related program I have installed is Dell Power Manager lite.

Windows 10 64bit, i7-5500U, 8GB Ram, 1tb HDD.

Comment: Is this machine attached to a Domain network? If so, then there's a good chance it's the network administrator controlling it via GPO.

Comment: It is very likely that the Dell Power Manager Lite changes/refreshes the Power scheme and thus altering the state of the power button. See if you have a setting in the Dell Power Manager. It is possible this is a bug. If you want to be sure, uninstall the Dell Power Manager and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I see where you're coming from, but I think its far more likely that its an issue with the Power Manager. The power button state is part of the Power Scheme, and the Dell Power Management also controls this.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Not a domain computer, its my personal computer.

Comment: @LPChip Possible, but that is not an option in dell power manager, so IDK. Is there a way I could monitor for when that is changed, and see who/what changed it?

Comment: @user173724 You can temporarily uninstall Dell Power Manager. This would be much more simple than trying to monitor what is changing the setting.

Comment: Sighhhhhhhhhhhh, So there is not a way to monitor what application changed that setting?